# Register a menu - Error Header

Tags: php, functions, menus

Could someone have the same error when im trying to [register a menu](https://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus)?

function.php

```
function register_my_menu() {
  register_nav_menu('header-menu',__( 'Header Menu' ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menu' );
```

error

> function register_my_menu() { register_nav_menu('header-menu',__(
>   'Header Menu' )); } add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menu' ); Warning:
>   Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output
>   started at
>   /home/milibyte/public_html/wp-content/themes/test/functions.php:4) in
>   /home/milibyte/public_html/wp-admin/includes/misc.php on line 1126

[GitHub](https://github.com/fdesur/phpProblem.git)

Regards!

Comment: check this out https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/fixing-cannot-modify-header-error/

Comment: i put a github.

Comment: Sure share us your file.

Comment: Where in github ?

Comment: Exactly what I suggested an hour ago...  Start your file with `<?php`

Comment: ohh in the function.php. sorry didn't get it. yes, is working.. thanks! everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
function register_my_menu() {
    register_nav_menu( 'header-menu',__( 'Header Menu' ) );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'register_my_menu' );
```

Comment: is not nesesary to close ? "?>"

Comment: Not unless you need to switch over to HTML mode.  I never end a file with ?>  too often there is a hidden space or too many carrage returns after, and that can cause similar troubles like you had

Answer (score 1):

The error may display itself when there are:

- Blank lines at the top or bottom of a document
- Too many spaces before, in between or after the beginning  PHP tags
- There are too many unneeded spaces or blank lines in a specific part of a document

Just to debug, try to do something like this.

```
function register_my_menu() { 
     //do nothing 
} 
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menu' );
```

If you Google that issue you will get amazed by how many people have that just because of extra spaces or wrong things on the `functions.php`.

Comment: but my functions.php is so small!!

Comment: It doesn't matter, we just need one character in a wrong position to make it it fails, did you check //do nothing?

Comment: exist something to check the lines?

Comment: ahh sorry, yes i check and the problem persist!

Comment: So, we know is something wrong in you functions.php, since it's small you can remove everything and start pasting back small pieces of codes to see when the error shows up again.

Comment: can be old the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are running your action too soon.

Don't run it at 'init', use 'after_setup_theme' instead.

`add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'register_my_menu' );`

Comment: thanks, but the problem persist.

Comment: Do you have php wrappers around the code?  If not, that could cause this.

Comment: i did, I use notepadd c++ with no BOM and check wrappers.

Comment: The way you list the message, it looks like it's spitting out your php code, then saying headers are already sent.  This sounds like you did not start the file with <?php

Comment: i put it in github.

Comment: Just knowing that, doesn't allow me to do anything to help you.  github is a big site.